# KnockoutJS is updating ALL the objects in an array rather than just One

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So this is kind of a complicated one. I will do my best to explain it here but have set up a Fiddle which demonstrates the issue ... You can find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gary_stenstrom/BAXsS/)

I first created a Javascript Data Transfer Object It's more than a simple DTO, in that it attempts to incorporate KO mapping capabilities, so that the contents of the DTO can be retrieved as a KO Object using a "GetKnockout()" method. It stores the KO Object as well as the object used to initialize the properties internally in private properties (_lotKO, _origData).

```
var LotDTO = function (data) {

    //#region Public Properties
    var name            = (data != null) ? data.Name : null;
    var desc            = (data != null) ? data.Description : null;
    var model           = (data != null) ? data.Model : null;
    var buildStage      = (data != null) ? data.BuildStage : null;
    var softwareVersion = (data != null) ? data.SoftwareVersion : null;
    var config          = (data != null) ? data.Configuration : new Array();
    var serialNumbers   = (data != null) ? data.SerialNumbers : new Array();
    //#endregion 

    //#region Private Properties
    var _lotKO = null;
    var _origData = data;
    //#endregion

    //#region Public Methods
    var GetKnockout = function () {
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a knockout object that can be used to bind to UI elements. It is important to remeber that the values in the knockout object do NOT sync up with the LotDTO values.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        var self = this;
        if (_lotKO == null) {
            SetKnockout(self);
        }

        return _lotKO;
    }

    var Reset = function () {
        /// <summary>Reverts all the object properties back to their original values</summary>
        /// 
        var self = this;
        name            = (_origData != null) ? _origData.Name : null;
        desc            = (_origData != null) ? _origData.Description : null;
        model           = (_origData != null) ? _origData.Model : null;
        buildStage      = (_origData != null) ? _origData.BuildStage : null;
        softwareVersion = (_origData != null) ? _origData.SoftwareVersion : null;
        config          = (_origData != null) ? _origData.Configuration : new Array();
        serialNumbers   = (_origData != null) ? _origData.BrewerSerialNumbers : new Array();
        //
        // If the KO object has already been defined the reset it's definitions
        if (_lotKO != null) {
              //alert("resetting knockout");
            SetKnockout(self);
        }
    }
    //#endregion

    //#region Private Methods
    function SetKnockout(self) {

        _lotKO = {
            Name            : ko.observable(self.Name),
            Description     : ko.observable(self.Description),
            Model           : ko.observable(self.Model),
            BuildStage      : ko.observable(self.BuildStage),
            SoftwareVersion : ko.observable(self.SoftwareVersion),
            Configuration   : ko.observableArray(self.Configuration),
            SerialNumbers   : ko.observableArray(self.SerialNumbers)
        };
    }

    //#endregion

    return {
        Name            : name,
        Description     : desc,
        Model           : model,
        BuildStage      : buildStage,
        SoftwareVersion : softwareVersion,
        Configuration   : config,
        SerialNumbers   : serialNumbers,
        GetKnockout     : GetKnockout,
        Reset: Reset
    };
}
```

In my [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gary_stenstrom/BAXsS/) I have also created a function which, when called, will instantiate several instances of the DTO object and return them in an array.

So far so good...

Now when I run the Fiddle the form fills properly, with the "Name" property value being display in an Label and a text box. The "SerialNumbers" are correctly bound to the drop down list box.

As you click the "Next"/"Prev" buttons the "GetKnockout()" function of the next DTO in the array is called and  bound to the form. "GetKnockout()" maps the DTO to a new KO ViewModel, unless a KO ViewModel has already been created, whereby it would then return the existing KO ViewModel. (***IMPORTANT***: Keep in mind that there are only 3 DTO's in the example and I have not bothered with error handling so do not "Next/Prev" too far!)

```
function BtnNext_OnClick(event) {

    APPScreen.SelectedLotIDX = APPScreen.SelectedLotIDX + 1;
    ko.applyBindings(APPScreen.SelectedLot().GetKnockout(), $("#dvContainer")[0]);

}
```

So far everything works as expected: You can see the contents of the Label, textbox and drop down list changing appropriately as you move through the DTO's.

Here's where the problems start ... In the text box, modify the name, then go to the next/previous DTO by clicking one of the "Next"/"Prev" buttons. You'll notice that when you changed the name for one you change them for ALL instances! So this started me looking at my use of "this" and led me to some changes. I continue to be confused as to why changing the value of the bound text box should update ALL instances, however. When you hit the "Reset()" button it correctly resets the value of ***just the instance being displayed***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you bind to model and then when you click the button you changing values of your underlying model. What you should do. Is to have an array of models and then when clicking next/prev just switch the object that you are displaying/editing.

Check simplified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tkirda/BAXsS/1/

```
<div id="dvContainer">
    <div data-bind="with: CurrentItem">
         <h2 data-bind="text:Name"></h2>

        <input type="text" data-bind="value:Name" />
        <br />
        <select data-bind="options: $root.SerialNumbers"></select>
        <br />
    </div>
    <button id="btnPrev" data-bind="click: Prev">Prev</button>
    <button id="btnNext" data-bind="click: Next">Next</button>
    <button id="btnReset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function Item(name) {
    this.Name = ko.observable(name);
}

var model = {
    items: ko.observableArray([new Item('A'), new Item('B'), new Item('C')]),
    SerialNumbers: ['1', '2', '3'],
    index: ko.observable(0)
};

model.CurrentItem = ko.observable(model.items()[0]);

model.Next = function () {
    model.index(model.index() + 1);
    model.CurrentItem(model.items()[model.index()]);
};

model.Prev = function () {
    model.index(model.index() - 1);
    model.CurrentItem(model.items()[model.index()]);
};

ko.applyBindings(model, $("#dvContainer")[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have been going over it for the past couple of days and I guess where I am confused is in your key comment -- "when you click the button you [are] changing values of your underlying model"-- . I do not understand how I am doing that. When I click the Next/Prev button aren't I binding to a completely different model, presumably unassociated with any of the other models?

Comment: For example, you have view model with cars collection. Then you have property selectedCar. Then when you want to switch to another car, you should not update properties of selectedCar to reflect other car, but set new object/model for the  selectedCar property itself. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does and your solution, with some implementation-specific tweaks works perfectly! It will take some repetition for it to REALLY sink in, so hopefully I will have the opportunity to use it more frequently! Thanks again! (gave an extra upvote for the explanation)